# How to Fix Right Click Touchpad Not Working on Ubuntu 18.0

Tags: ubuntu, right-click, touchpad

This means that clicking in the bottom right area of your touchpad won’t work in Ubuntu 18.04 by default
if you have any solution please share, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open The terminal and to do this

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository universe
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
$ sudo apt  update
$ gnome-tweaks
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. It was not a bug but actually a touchpad behavior on Ubuntu 18.04, if your laptop’s touchpad doesn’t have ‘physical buttons’ for left and right click. So, the **right click can be achieved by tapping with two fingers**.

You can easily change this behavior and enable right-click on Ubuntu 18.04.
Please check, https://itsfoss.com/fix-right-click-touchpad-ubuntu/